# Powershell matching multiline characters between two strings

Tags: regex, powershell

I can not work out how to extract everything (multiline) from a log files. here is the sample I need to extract from:

```
FieldCoilConnectivity=00
ConfigError=readback radio section
NfcErrorCode=0

[compare Errors]
```

and I need to extract only this part:

```
readback radio section
NfcErrorCode=0
```

I am using powershell with this script:

```
$input_path = ‘C:\Users\martin.kuracka\Desktop\temp\Analyza_chyb_SUEZ_CommTEst\022020\*_E.log’
$output_file = ‘C:\Users\martin.kuracka\Desktop\temp\Analyza_chyb_SUEZ_CommTEst\032020\extracted.txt’
$regex = ‘(?<=ConfigError=)(.*)(?=[compare Errors])’
select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file
```

but it ends up only with this:

```
readback radio secti
```

not even full first line is extracted. can you help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issue:

- You are opening the file in a line-by-line reading mode, you need to read the file in as a single variable (use `Get-Content $filepath -Raw`)
- You did not escape `[` and the `[compare Errors]` is treated as a character class that matches a single character from a set (you need `\[compare Errors]`)
- You need a `RegexOptions.Singleline` modifier or `(?s)` inline option to make `.` match across linebreaks
- You need to use a non-greedy `.*?`, not `.*` to stop at the first occurrence of `[compar e Errors]`

Use

```
$regex = '(?s)(?<=ConfigError=).*?(?=\s*\[compare Errors])'
Get-Content $input_path -Raw | Select-String -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file
```

Note I removed the capturing parentheses from around `.*?` since you are not using the submatch, and I added `\s*` before `\[` to "trim" the resulting match from the trailing whitespace.

**Regex details**

- `(?s)` - singleline mode making `.` match across lines
- `(?<=ConfigError=)` -  a location immediately preceded with `ConfigError`
- `.*?` - any 0 or more chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\s*\[compare Errors])` - immediately to the right, there must be 0+ whitespaces followed with `[compare Errors]`.

Comment: I have written a general [article about extracting strings between two strings with regex](https://www.buymeacoffee.com/wstribizew/extracting-text-two-strings-regular-expressions), too, feel free to read if you have a problem approaching your current similar problem.